# Python slice a string and add to a list

Tags: python

If I have a string (that has for example 76 characters), and I want to split it into separate  smaller strings, each having 19 characters and add them into a list, how would I do this?

Comment: `string[start:end]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Use the `range`'s step parameter. Then slice using `l[number:number+19]`

```
l2=[l[i:i+19] for i in range(0,len(l),19)]
```